# transpose 2 columns against the rest of the datafame R

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot

I have a data table:

```
Country    AcctType    Instrument    Stream        Line        sum           period
Afghanistan   A           1            D          CFD DD        133        August2019
Afghanistan   B           2            E          CFD DD        108        August2019
Afghanistan   A           3            E          CFD DD        108        September2019
Albania       A           1            D          CFD DD        374        August2019
Albania       B           2            D          CFD DD        400        September2019
```

I only want to transpose the sum and period columns and group by country first the following columns so that the output would look like:

```
Country    AcctType    Instrument    Stream        Line        August2019    September2019
Afghanistan   A           1            D          CFD DD        133               -
Afghanistan   A           3            E          CFD DD        108               -
Afghanistan   B           2            E          CFD DD         -               108       
Albania       A           1            D          CFD DD        374               -
Albania       B           2            D          CFD DD         -               400
```

I know there's a method with dcast but i couldn't find that much helpful documentation on it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick solution would be

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = period,
    values_from = sum
)
```

---

Edit:

```
# add an additional row with another month
df <- rbind(df, c("Andorra", "C", 1, "D", "CFD DD", 107, "October2019"))

df %>% 
   pivot_wider(
     names_from = period,
     values_from = sum
)

# A tibble: 6 x 8
# Country     AcctType Instrument Stream Line   August2019 September2019 October2019
# <chr>       <chr>    <chr>      <chr>  <chr>  <chr>      <chr>         <chr>    
# Afghanistan A        1          D      CFD DD 133        NA            NA         
# Afghanistan B        2          E      CFD DD 108        NA            NA         
# Afghanistan A        3          E      CFD DD NA         108           NA         
# Albania     A        1          D      CFD DD 374        NA            NA         
# Albania     B        2          D      CFD DD NA         400           NA         
# Andorra     C        1          D      CFD DD NA         NA            107
```

Comment: thanks alot, this worked a treat, the example i gave was just a snapshot and in reality the table has more months in the period, with your script it gives the output i want but the dates are not in ascending order, is there a way to specify that ?

Comment: `pivot_wider` creates the month columns in the order R encounters the categories on the pivotting variable (in this case `period`). I show an example in the answer above. So, if you order the dataset chronologically, you should get the created columns in chronological order as well

Comment: @r_mat Also, not to beg, but if you found my answer useful and you've already upvoted it, could you please re-upvote it again? Because on Stack Overflow there is this problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285181/once-i-reach-15-reputation-will-my-old-votes-be-taken-into-account

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), ... ~ period, value.var = 'sum')
#      Country AcctType Instrument Stream   Line August2019 September2019
#1: Afghanistan        A          1      D CFD DD        133            NA
#2: Afghanistan        A          3      E CFD DD         NA           108
#3: Afghanistan        B          2      E CFD DD        108            NA
#4:     Albania        A          1      D CFD DD        374            NA
#5:     Albania        B          2      D CFD DD         NA           400
```